# How can I configure Juju for deployment on OS X?

Tags: server, juju, continuous-deployment

I am non-tech entrepreneur. I have developed a Rails app. I want to deploy it live. Can anyone guide me on how to use Ubuntu server + Juju on my laptop to deploy the app live on internet.

Comment: The link David posted links to the documentation, make sure you check out the Juju vagrant boxes in the docs!

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the linked question. Similar, yes, but Swap's question is specifically about using Juju on OS X. Also, the linked answer is outdated, containing multiple broken links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using Juju to Deploy Your Rails Application](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/howto-rails) is a great place to start. That documents what you need to do to deploy a rails application with Juju.

For development purposes, the [Juju Vagrant Workflow for OS X](https://jujucharms.com/docs/devel/howto-vagrant-workflow) will get you up and running with a Vagrant virtual machine in order to fully experience Juju using the local provider. This is how I do most of my development work.

When you're ready to put your application live, you would then use your own private cloud or a public one such as Amazon.

For example, I'd write a yaml file to tell the Rails charm about my rail application. Next, I'd fire up a Vagrant virtual machine, which will start me with a fully functional local environment to test with. I'd deploy rails, passing it the yaml file I created, and then test to verify that my application works as expected.

At that point, I'd shut down the vm, returning to my OS X terminal, and `juju switch amazon`, `juju bootstrap` the environment, and then deploy the application.

That's all a bit high level, but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance . I can't vote you because the vote requires +15 reputations. Best